# $L^{p}$ identity for the maximal operator.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, harmonic-analysis

This is probably a very easy question, but I'm failing to understand it. Given a function $f \in L^{p}(\mathbb{R}^n)$, $1<p\leq \infty$, we define the *uncentered maximal function* of $f$ as
$$
\tilde{M}f(x) = \sup_{x\in B}\frac{1}{\mu(B)}\int_{B}\left| f(y)\right|d\mu(y),
$$

where the supremum is taken over all the balls that contain $x$, and $\mu$ can be the Lebesgue measure. Then, Stein claims (it's from the book "Harmonic Analysis, Real Variable Theory") that
$$
\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}\left(\tilde{M}f\right)^{p}d\mu = p\int_{0}^{\infty}\mu\left( \{x\in \mathbb{R}^n; \tilde{M}f(x) > \alpha \}\right)\alpha^{p-1}d\alpha.
$$

I can't prove this identity. If you make the variable change $\alpha^{p}=y$, then it becomes
$$
\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}\left(\tilde{M}f\right)^{p}d\mu = \int_{0}^{\infty}\mu\left( \{x\in \mathbb{R}^n; \tilde{M}f(x)^p > y\}\right)dy,
$$

but is this identity obvious? What am I missing? I appreciate any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $f \in L^p$. Then we have
\begin{align*}p \int_0^\infty \alpha^{p-1} \mu(\{x \in X : \lvert f(x) \rvert > \alpha\}) \mathrm{d}\alpha
&= p \int_0^\infty \alpha^{p-1} \int_X \chi_{\{x \in X : \lvert f(x) \rvert > \alpha\}} \mathrm{d}\mu \mathrm{d}\alpha \\
&= \int_X \int_0^\infty p \alpha^{p-1} \chi_{\{x \in X : \lvert f(x) \rvert > \alpha\}} \mathrm{d}\alpha \mathrm{d}\mu \\
&= \int_X \int_0^{\lvert f(x)\rvert} p \alpha^{p-1} \mathrm{d}\alpha \mathrm{d}\mu = \int_X \lvert f(x) \rvert^p \mathrm{d}\mu,
\end{align*}
where we used Fubini and $\chi_M$ is the characteristic function of the set $M$.